# SqlCommand doesn't recognize the column names from the tables selected

Tags: vb.net, sqlcommand

I just posted a previous question about updating the connection string. It works fine, but it makes my select command fail. The SqlException was handled that Invalid column name `'Username', 'Password', 'UserType'` which they are already in my User table from my database.

Below is my select command:

```
myConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=RAVY-PC\RAVY;Database=CIEDC;Trusted_Connection=True")
myConnection.Open()

myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT UserType FROM User WHERE UserName = @User AND Password = @Pass", myConnection)

txtUserType.Text = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

Since it catched the above error, I've no idea what was the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Try placing square backets around `User` to quote the tablename (User is a keyword):

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT UserType FROM [User] WHERE UserName = @User AND Password = @Pass", myConnection)
```

Comment: But it is the same to another table named "tblStaff".

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn : i'm afraid that sentence makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenient, but I meant my real table here is tblStaff. And I tried there, but it still does not work.

Comment: I tried deleting all column names and use this belowing command instead:  "Select * From tblStaff" and it works fine. So this causes from column name. Could you please guide me how I should proceed. Thanks guy...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are setting your parameters:

```
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@User","MyUsername")
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Pass","MyPassword")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
myCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE UserName = @User AND Password = @Pass", myConnection)
```

Then add parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets around your column names. This will allow keywords to be used as column names. Try the following for example.

```
select [UserType] from tblStaff
```